# JS: querySelectorAll with respect to z-index

Tags: javascript, css, z-index

I would like to select all "div" elements that are children of the "body" and have z-index: 2 property set.

document.querySelectorAll('body > div');

How do I involve the z-index check on this querySelector?

Comment: why not just iterate through the `div` elements checking their zIndex property?

Comment: That's what i currently do, i just like to know the best solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you can't involve the "z-index" into the selector, because there's no CSS selector syntax for selecting elements based on CSS style attributes.

What you *could* do would be to achieve your "z-index: 2" styling by giving elements a particular class. You could then use the class in your selector ("body > div.zIndex2" or whatever).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i just didn't want to add new code since I already distinguish which "divs" I would like by having z-index:2 (which also serves on some animation in my code).

Comment: If the z-index is directly on the "style" attribute, then you *might* be able to make up a selector to examine the "style" attribute itself - that might be messy and it seems pretty fragile to me.

Comment: is this something like 'body > div[style= ... etc?

Comment: Yes - however that's probably pretty close to the edge of what the browsers are going to be able to do. I don't know whether there's good support for jQuery-style limited pattern matching, or if that's even part of the CSS3 spec.  Maybe it is though.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use jQuery for a selection like that and a custom selector like:

```
$.expr[':'].zIndex = function(obj) {
   if ($(obj).css('z-index')==2) return true;
   else return false;
}
```

Then call with:

```
$('body div:zIndex')
```

but you would need jQuery for this and I haven't tested it

Comment: Thanks, but I avoided jQuery on purpose from the beginning.

Comment: I which case I suspect the first comment which you're already doing is the best answer as I suspect this is all jQuery does with selectors.